# Reuse ggplot layers in multiple plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting tons of graphs which essentially use the same type of formatting. Just wondering if it possible to store these layers in a variable and reuse them.

Approach 1 (does not work)

```
t <- layer1() + layer2()
ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + t
```

Approach 2 (works but not very elegant)

```
t <- function(x) x + layer1() + layer2()
t(ggplot(df,aes(x,y))
```

Any suggestion along the lines of approach 1?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is, but it would be good if you explained exactly what `layer1()` and `layer2()` are supposed to be. What do they return? What do they do? Normally, I would just save the result of a `geom_*` call in a variable and add it in later.

Comment: Just a comment: you probably shouldn't overwrite a relatively common base function like `t()`.

Comment: @joran I was thinking of formatting layers like scale_x_continuous() and theme(). Does that make any difference what they do?

Comment: As you discovered, it should work the same. To avoid confusion, you should know that things like `scale_*` and `theme()` aren't generally called "layers" in ggplot. That word typically refers to geoms and stats.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

While I wait for some clarification, here are a few examples that demonstrate how to add previously created layers to an existing plot:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x = cyl,y = mpg)) + 
        geom_point()    
new_layer <- geom_point(data = mtcars,aes(x = cyl,y = hp),colour = "red")
new_layer1 <- geom_point(data = mtcars,aes(x = cyl,y = wt),colour = "blue")

p + new_layer

p + list(new_layer,new_layer1)
```

Answer (score 20):

Based on the [Joran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18747221/3888000), I now put my layers into a list, and add it in my plots. Works like a charm :

```
r = data.frame(
  time=c(5,10,15,20),
  mean=c(10,20,30,40),
  sem=c(2,3,1,4),
  param1=c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
  param2=c("X", "Y", "X", "Y")
)
gglayers = list(
  geom_point(size=3),
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sem, ymax=mean+sem), width=.3),
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 180, 240)),
  labs(
    x = "Time(minutes)",
    y = "Concentration"
  )
)
ggplot(data=r, aes(x=time, y=mean, colour=param1, shape=param1)) +
  gglayers +
  labs(
    color = "My param1\n",
    shape = "My param1\n"
  )
ggplot(data=r, aes(x=time, y=mean, colour=param2, shape=param2)) +
  gglayers +
  labs(
    color = "My param2\n",
    shape = "My param2\n"
  )
```

Comment: This answer wins for me because I don't need to specify the data source (meaning I can recycle the layers for a bunch of similarly-structured data frames)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but here is one that avoids the clunky t(ggplot(...)))

```
t<-function(...) ggplot(...) + layer1() + layer2()
t(df, aes(x, y))
```