# Use a diagram as background template in a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a geologist and I use TAS diagrams to understand what is going on with volcanoes. I'd like to make a fixed background/template with such a diagram:

[image]

On this background, I then wish to plot real data, e.g.

[image]

Here is my current code which makes the TAS diagram with ggplot, and then plots the data with the `geom_point` feature

```
library(ggplot2)

#create blank dataframe for tas plot
d = data.frame(x = c(40, 80), y = c(0,15))


theme_set(theme_bw(base_size=28))

#makes the TAS template
p <- ggplot(data=d, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_blank() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,15), expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(40,80), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  labs(y=expression(Na[2]*O + K[2]*O*~ wt~'%'), x=expression(SiO[2]*~ wt~'%'))+
  annotate("segment", x=45, xend=45, y=1, yend=5)+
  annotate("segment", x=45, xend=52, y=5, yend=5)+
  annotate("segment", x=52, xend=69, y=5, yend=8)+
  annotate("segment", x=76.5, xend=69, y=1, yend=8)+
  annotate("segment", x=69, xend=69, y=8, yend=13)+
  annotate("segment", x=45, xend=61.32, y=5, yend=13.7)+
  annotate("segment", x=52, xend=52, y=1, yend=5)+
  annotate("segment", x=57, xend=57, y=1, yend=5.9)+
  annotate("segment", x=63, xend=63, y=1, yend=6.9)+
  annotate("segment", x=52, xend=49.4, y=5, yend=7.3)+
  annotate("segment", x=57, xend=53.05, y=5.9, yend=9.25)+
  annotate("segment", x=63, xend=57.6, y=6.9, yend=11.7)+
  annotate("segment", x=41, xend=45, y=3, yend=3)+
  annotate("segment", x=41, xend=41, y=1, yend=3)+
  annotate("segment", x=41, xend=41, y=3, yend=7, linetype="dashed")+
  annotate("segment", x=41, xend=45, y=7, yend=9.4, linetype="dashed")+
  annotate("segment", x=45, xend=52.5, y=9.4, yend=14)+
  annotate("segment", x=49.4, xend=45, y=7.3, yend=9.4)+
  annotate("segment", x=53, xend=48.4, y=9.3, yend=11.5)+
  annotate("segment", x=57.6, xend=50.3, y=11.7, yend=15)

tas <- p + annotate("text", label = "Basalt", x = 48.5, y = 2, size=4)+
  annotate("text", label = "Basaltic\n andesite", x = 54.8, y = 2.7, size=4)+
  annotate("text", label = "Andesite", x = 60, y = 3.5, size=4)+
  annotate("text", label = "Dacite", x = 67.5, y = 4.2, size=4)+
  annotate("text", label = "Rhyolite", x = 72, y = 7, size=4)+
  annotate("text", label = "Trachy- \n basalt", x = 48.8, y = 5.7, size=4)+
  annotate("text", label = "Basaltic \n trachy- \n andesite", x = 52.5, y = 7, size=4)+
  annotate("text", label = "Trachy- \n andesite", x = 57.8, y = 8.2, size=4)+
  annotate("text", label = "Trachydacite", x = 65, y = 9, size=4)+
  annotate("text", label = "Trachyte", x = 62.5, y = 11.5, size=4)+
  annotate("text", label = "Picro- \n basalt", x = 43, y = 1.5, size=4)+
  annotate("text", label = "Basanite \n (Ol > 10%)", x = 44, y = 6, size=4)+
  annotate("text", label = "Tephrite \n (Ol < 10%)", x = 43.5, y = 7, size=4)+
  annotate("text", label = "Phono- \n tephrite", x = 48.5, y = 9.5, size=4)+
  annotate("text", label = "Tephri- \n phonolite", x = 52.5, y = 11.5, size=4)+
  annotate("text", label = "Phonolite", x = 57, y = 14, size=4)+
  annotate("text", label = "Foidite", x = 42, y = 12, size=4)
```

Plot data on the TAS template, change colour indicator, shape indicator. `geom_point`s are added to show different suites of data:

```
tas +
  geom_point(data = bkg_wr, aes(x=SiO2, y=Na2O+K2O), fill="gray92", shape=21,size=4)+
  geom_point(data = bkg_gl, aes(x=SiO2, y=Na2O+K2O), fill="gray92", shape=23, size=4)+
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=0.5))
```

Comment: Put your annotation layers in a list and then you can add them to any ggplot

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Reuse ggplot layers in multiple plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747091/reuse-ggplot-layers-in-multiple-plots)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try and fill everyone in. I know you're waiting with baited breath!

Comment: Hi @Dawn, I'm also a geologist looking at using TAS plotsin ggplot2. Are you ok if I use your script for making a TAS plot background? It's really useful! Thanks!!

Comment: By all means, help yourself. I still haven't had time to try the list option suggested by Jack Brookes. So if you want to try that and get back to us, that would be awesome.