# Changing ggtitle in a loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I would like to subset my dataset based on the value of one variable and draw a ggplot with the value of that variable as the name of the plot AND as the ggtitle and save each plot.

Finally I would like to combine all graphs into one page.

Here is a simplified example.

```r
y=rnorm(100, 0,1)
x=sample(100, 5, replace = T)

k=5
z=sample(k, 100, replace=T)

z <- factor(z, levels = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                    labels = c("red", "blue", "green", "purple", "yellow"))

dat=data.frame(y=y, x=x, z=z)
library(ggplot2)

for(i in seq_len(k))
{
dat2 = data.frame(dat[dat$z=='i',])

i <- ggplot(dat2, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle(i)
}

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(red, blue, green, purple,yellow, nrow = 2)
```

I am having trouble with saving the variable as i and line with the ggtitle(). The title should be different colors for each graph: red, blue, green....etc.

Thank you.

Comment: `dat[dat$z=='i',]` should be `dat[dat$z==i,]` for your code to work. Why do you assign the plot to `i` in the loop? It's confusing. Anyway your whole code can be replaced by a one-line call to add facets :)

Comment: Oh I just realised what you're trying to achieve with your `i <- ggplot(...)`! That's not going to work - I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subsetting is incorrect: you used the string `'i'` instead of the variable `i`.

You could simply use facets instead of your `for` loop and `grid.arrange`:

```r
dat=data.frame(y=y, x=x, z=z)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ z)
```

If you want to loop and arrange, you need to use a list:

```r
plots <- list()

for(z in levels(z)) {
  dat2 = data.frame(dat[dat$z==z,])

  plots[[z]] <- ggplot(dat2, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(z)
}

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(plots$red, plots$blue, plots$green, plots$purple, plots$yellow, nrow = 2)
```

Note that I use the values of z for the looping variable rather than `1:5`.

This is more elegantly done as:

```r
colors <- c("red", "blue", "green", "purple", "yellow")
N <- 100

dat <- data.frame(x = sample(N, 5, replace = T),
                  y = rnorm(N, 0,1),
                  z = sample(colors, N, replace=T))

plot_color <- function(col, dat) {
  dat2 <- dat[dat$z==col,]

  ggplot(dat2, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(col)
}

plots <- purrr::map(colors, plot_color, dat = dat)
do.call(grid.arrange, c(plots, nrow = 2))
```

Comment: Yes, for this example that would work, but in my original code the graphs are slightly different for each subset. Hence, difficult to produce graphs in one go.

Comment: @Stata_user If they're not the same graphs, I am not sure it makes sense to create them in the loop. You'll end up with `if (i == "red") {...} else if (i == "green") {...}` which is a complete anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks @antoine-sac. I did something like this. It seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop or you can do it shorter and faster with the combo lapply/do.call;

```
myplots = lapply(seq_len(k), function(i){
    p <- ggplot(data.frame(dat[dat$z==i,]), aes(x=x, y=y)) +
        geom_point() +
        ggtitle(i)
    ggsave(paste0(i,'.png'),p)        # if you want to save each plot
    return(p)
})
do.call(grid.arrange, myplots)
```

#### to have individual plots in environment

```
names(myplots) = seq_len(k)
list2env(myplots)
```

#### or do this individually (e.g. inside the loop/lapply);

```
assign('blue',myplots[[1]])
```

Comment: No, sorry still not it. As I mentioned before, I can't lump all results into one dataframe. I need 1. to subset 2. manipulate data(not shown here) and only then 3. graph. My biggest problem is putting the value label as the title of each graph.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is unclear. If you can't put all data in it in one dataframe, how do you expect to subset? Do you want to make a list of appropriate data frames (and replace seq_len(k))? Do you want to add if statements in the plotting function? If all graphs are different, why use a loop? Maybe this will help  you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747091/reuse-ggplot-layers-in-multiple-plots. The answers also show how to put the value label as ggtitle, as you asked. I edited my answer.