# switch titles of qqplot using lapply or loops on dataframe

Tags: r, function, loops, lapply

I'm trying to create Q-Q Plots using the car package for each variable in a dataframe. I'd like the titles of each plot to change and correspond to each variable being plotted. But all I've managed are errors or the plot generated with the code below. I'd ultimately like to have separate lines on each qqplot for multiple groups

```
library(car)
data(cars)
labels = colnames(cars)

newfun = function(x) {
 qqtitle = paste(labels, "QQ Plot", sep = " ") 
 plot = qqPlot(x, main = qqtitle)
  return(plot)
  }

lapply(cars,newfun)
```

Ideally a QQ plot per variable in the dataframe should be printed and have correct title at the top, great if it can also include groups. I'd like to avoid a ggplot solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing ggtitle in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357879/changing-ggtitle-in-a-loop)

Comment: Thanks @kstew , however I wanted a solution using the packages specified, not ggplot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you define the `labels` outside of `newfun` you could use `mapply` and a slightly modified `newfun`

```
labels <- colnames(cars)

newfun <- function(x, y) qqPlot(x, main = paste(y, "QQ Plot", sep = " "))

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
mapply(newfun, cars, labels)
```

[image]

Explanation: `newfun` is now a function of `x` (the data) and `y` (the column names). We then use `mapply` (or `Map`) to loop through the columns and column names of `cars`.